# Add TextView programmatically but text color become gray like disabled

Tags: android, colors, textview

Why does my textview automatically change the color to gray as if they were disabled when I add them programmatically? I am sure I did not set any color to gray in my layout.

Here's my code for adding textview programmatically:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View chat = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list_item, null);
((TextView)chat.findViewById(R.id.chat_name)).setText(obj.getString("username"));
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.chat_list);
container.addView(chat);
```

here is my layout item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/chat_view"
        android:clickable="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/chat_propic"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/face"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <!-- name and last message-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="10"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:id="@+id/chat_name"
                    android:text="UserNAMEEEE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:id="@+id/chat_time"
                    android:text="30/05/2015"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:id="@+id/chat_message"
                android:text="asjkdgaksgkdagskdakjsdhklahskld"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="#ff828282"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: myTextView.setTextColor(0xAARRGGBB);

Comment: @Yoh Hendry can you please accept my answer if it helped ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a line after creating the `TextView`

```
chat.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault);
```

Comment: chat.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault);

Answer (score 0):

Might not work but I remember my friend having a problem similar to this and I told him this: "activate" the textView.

```
chat.setActivated(TRUE);
```

The "TRUE" might be wrong, there might be something like View.ACTIVATED or so ,test it out yourself please :)

Let me know if you need anything else and if it worked.